# ImageField and Django Wizard Form

Tags: python, django

I've created a wizard form that worked up until I added an ImageField.

When I got to submit the form with an image file chosen I get returned to the page saying the ImageField is required.

I've set up the MEDIA_ROOT and have that working.

Here are the snippets of code I think are in question:

models.py

```
# CreatePuzzleWizard forms
class uploadForm(forms.Form):
    puzzle_image        = forms.ImageField()
    puzzle_name         = forms.CharField(max_length=30, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}))
    puzzle_description  = forms.CharField(max_length=300, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}))
```

views.py

```
class CreatePuzzleWizard(SessionWizardView):
    template_name = "create.html"
    file_storage = FileSystemStorage(location=os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, 'tmp'))

    def done(self, form_list, **kwargs):
        form_data = process_form_data(form_list)
        return render('complete.html', {'form_list', form_list})

def process_form_data(form_list):
    form_data = [form.cleaned_data for form in form_list]

    # do stuff with form data

    return form_data
```

I get this issue:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/2pwNn.jpg

I can't seem to find the problem on the internet. I'm using Django 1.6.1

Answer (score 2):

The Django Docs specify that there is unfortunately a little work to do when binding an uploaded file to a form field:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/api/#binding-uploaded-files-to-a-form

Comment: got an unexpected keyword argument 'upload_to', I tried but It didn't work.

Comment: Sorry!  I found the info in the Django Docs, thankfully.

Comment: ah! It turned out to be this: <form action="/create/" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">{% csrf_token %}   Turns out it needed the endctype...